# Ошибка в цикле for

Tags: android-studio

Что не нравиться компилятору?

```
for (sub < 1) {
    r = r - 1;
}
```

пишет

> ">" or "," expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (sub = 0; sub < 1; sub++) {
    r = r - 1;
}
```

Comment: Вы ошиблись. Правильный ответ `for (sub = 0; sub < 1; --sub) {...`